# Show multiple markers on Google Maps.

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps, google-places

I'm using the following JavaScript code to display Google Maps in my ASP.Net website. With this code I have added Google Places search that suggests results/places as the user types. I am displaying properties based on the searched location. However, I would like to display markers of the searched properties as well. I found a solution here: http://www.dotnetbull.com/2013/06/multiple-marker-with-labels-in-google.html but considering my limited knowledge of JavaScript I wasn't able to integrate it with my existing code to display places search along with markers on Google Maps. If you could please help me get it working I'll be thankful.

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=places"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function LoadGoogleMAP() {

        //Gets value of latitude and longitude of the search location from txtLatitude and txtLongitude textboxes. 
        var lat = document.getElementById('<%=txtLatitude.ClientID%>').value;
        var lon = document.getElementById('<%=txtLongitude.ClientID%>').value;
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon)

        var markers = [];
        var mapOptions = {
                center: myLatlng,
                zoom: 14,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                marker: true
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);

        // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.  
        var input = (document.getElementById('MainContent_txtSearch'));
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.CENTER].push(input);

        var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox((input));

        // Listen for the event fired when the user selects an item from the  
        // pick list. Retrieve the matching places for that item.  
        google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function () {
            var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

            if (places.length == 0) {
                return;
            }

            for (var i = 0, marker; marker = markers[i]; i++) {
                marker.setMap(null);
            }

            // For each place, get the icon, place name, and location.  
            markers = [];
            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            for (var i = 0, place; place = places[i]; i++) {
                var image = {
                    url: place.icon,
                    size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
                    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                    anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
                    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
                };

                // Create a marker for each place.  
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    icon: image,
                    title: place.name,
                    position: place.geometry.location
                });

                markers.push(marker);

                bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
            }

            map.fitBounds(bounds);
            map.setZoom(15);
            
        });
        
        // current map's viewport.  
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function () {
            var bounds = map.getBounds();
            searchBox.setBounds(bounds);
        });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code from [Official Google Doc](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox):

```
function initialize() {

  var markers = [];
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  var defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
      new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8902, 151.1759),
      new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8474, 151.2631));
  map.fitBounds(defaultBounds);

  // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
  var input = /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(
      document.getElementById('pac-input'));
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

  var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(
    /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(input));

  // Listen for the event fired when the user selects an item from the
  // pick list. Retrieve the matching places for that item.
  google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function() {
    var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

    if (places.length == 0) {
      return;
    }
    for (var i = 0, marker; marker = markers[i]; i++) {
      marker.setMap(null);
    }

    // For each place, get the icon, place name, and location.
    markers = [];
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    for (var i = 0, place; place = places[i]; i++) {
      var image = {
        url: place.icon,
        size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
      };
// Create a marker for each place.
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        icon: image,
        title: place.name,
        position: place.geometry.location
      });

      markers.push(marker);

      bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
    }

    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  });

  // Bias the SearchBox results towards places that are within the bounds of the
  // current map's viewport.
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
    var bounds = map.getBounds();
    searchBox.setBounds(bounds);
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```